# The application goes to the background, after 10 minutes it stops. *$interval function*

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic3, intervals

I need of yours help with one problem con ionic
The problem is with an *$interval function*

It works perfectly for me when the application is in the foreground. However, when the application goes to the background, after 10 minutes it stops.

I'm using ionic 3,
and when I run the application on an android device is where I get this problem.

Has someone happened to him?
how did they solve it? 
Beforehand thank you very much.

```
 cuentaRegresiva(minutes) {
 try {
  var n = - (minutes * 60);
  var contexto = this;
  window.setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(n);
    n++;
    if(n == 0){
      contexto.horariosLaborales = contexto.horarios.obtenerHorarios();
      console.log("El horario llego a cuetnaRegresiva con: "+ contexto.horariosLaborales);
      if (contexto.horariosLaborales) {
        console.log('SE ENVÍA LA PETICIÓN');
        //event
      } else {
        console.log('NO SE ENVÍA LA PETICIÓN - No esta en el horario laboral');
      }
      n = - (minutes * 60);
    }
  },1000);
} catch (e) {
  console.log("===  ERROR  ===");
  console.log(e);
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: Browsers slow down timer firing for non-focused windows.

Comment: but he executed it on the real device, specifically on an android.

Comment: It's still the browser engine. In order to save battery etc background applications are treated differently.

Comment: Applications can't run in the background forever on Android. You need to use a Service.

Comment: What I need to send a request every so often, how is it possible to solve it if it is not with a timer?